gam different results with variable smoothed by moving average from itsmr or zoo
I have a time series of 1853 monthly averaged sea surface temperatures (El Niño region 3.4). These data shows strong noise,hence  I smooth the variable with smooth.ma from itsmr package or rollmean of the zoo package over 10 years. Modeling with mgcv::gam gives two very different reluts including one warning.
Head of the data:NINO.34
require(itsmr)
require(zoo)
require(mgcv)
#head of sample data
dput(NINO.34 <- data.frame(
  yr.mnth = c("Jan 1870", "Feb 1870", "Mar 1870", "Apr 1870"),
  tmp_C = c(25.6, 25.6, 26.4, 27.0)
))
# Create  2 smoothed dataframes
# smoothed with **itsmr**
my_df <- mutate(NINO.34, 
                tmp.ma = smooth.ma(tmp_C, 121),  # 10 year moving average
                tnm = as.numeric(yr.mnth))
#smoothed with **zoo**
my_df.2 <- mutate(NINO.34, 
                tmp_rlmn = c(rep(NA, 120), rollmean(tmp_C, 121)),  # 10 year #rolling mean
                tnm = as.numeric(yr.mnth))

# Models with smooth term for year-month
# Model with moving average from smooth.ma

gam_ma <- gam(my_df, tmp.ma ~ s(tnm, k = 5), method = "REML")  
# message: In newton(lsp = lsp, X = G$X, y = G$y, Eb = G$Eb, UrS = G$UrS, L = #G$L,  :
#  Fitting terminated with step failure 


